# CompareValidator firing incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have two text boxes on my .aspx page, say TextBox1 and TextBox2. Each of them have `RangeValidators` attached to them, so that the user is restricted to entering only a certain range of integers. Moreover, the value in TextBox2 cannot exceed the value in TextBox1. For this, I'm using a `CompareValidator` on TextBox2. The `ControlToCompare` property is set to TextBox1, the `Type` property is set to Integer and `Operator` property is set to `LessThanEqual`.

When I enter valid integer data (say 100) in TextBox1 and non-integer data in TextBox2 (say 90.5), the RangeValidator correctly fires to inform me that the data in TextBox2 is not valid. But the CompareValidator also fires, saying the value in TextBox2 exceeds the value in TextBox1, which is incorrect.

Is there a way to stop the CompareValidator from firing if the value in TextBox1 violates the RangeValidator conditions in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

So `TextBox1` contains "100" and `TextBox2` "90.5"? Then the first value is higher than the second which is invalid since you have defined `LessThanEqual` as valid.

Use `GreaterThanEqual` instead since "TextBox2 cannot exceed the value in TextBox1". You are validating `TextBox1`.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been 'ControlToCompare' and not 'ControlToValidate'. Edited my question. The rest of the issue remains the same.